# JqueryMobile lose the style after append

Tags: jquery-mobile

Can somebody help me with this

http://jsfiddle.net/wwRNh/52/

How can I append an element and preserve its style ?

I have tried $(....).trigger(create);

Thanks

Comment: Hi mate, you should add your code to your post in case your jsfiddle link gets modified. So that, you'll the availability of the content of your post to future visitors :).

Answer (score 2):

Trigger the `refresh` event of the `listview`, just after appending your object, by using:

```
$("ul").listview("refresh");
```

You should then have the following JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn1").click(function(){

        $("ul").append("<li><a href="+"#page2"+">Page Two</a></li>");

        // Trigger refresh event
        $("ul").listview("refresh"); 

    });
});
```